# Choosing a sphere with finitely many intersections with a curve

Tags: differential-topology, curves, diffeomorphism

Let $\Phi:U\mapsto V$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism between two open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. for two points $x,y \in U$ let $$\gamma(t) = tx + (1-t)y$$ be a curve in U. Can i always choose a $r\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $$\partial B_r(\Phi(y))\cap im(\Phi\circ\gamma)$$ is finite?

Comment: Yes. This follows from the fact that for almost all $r$ the sphere of radius $r$ will be transverse to the curve.

Comment: @TedShifrin and beeing transverse automatically means, that it only intersects finitly often? care to expand on this? Also how do i show that it transverses for "most $r$"?

Comment: Compactness of the 0-dimensional submanifold will tell you finiteness. Perhaps the easiest approach is to apply Sard's Theorem to the function $f(z) = \|z-y\|^2$ on the curve.

Comment: @TedShifrin ok i get now, that the "number of intersections" is at most countable, since it has to be of measure zero. But how does compactness now prove, that this countable set is finite?

Comment: It is a closed 0-dimensional submanifold of the sphere, which is compact. Hence it's a compact 0-dimensional submanifold. Any such thing consists of a finite number of points.